# Why is Podman trying to pull an image that already exists after loading from file?

Tags: image, containers, coreos, podman

I am working in an air-gapped environment running Fedora CoreOS which comes packaged with Podman. I have several container images I have been working on transporting into the air-gapped environment. In order to do this I have followed these steps:

1. I acquired the images on a machine with internet access. Some of the images were pulled into Podman from my Docker registry using `podman pull docker-daemon:docker.io/my-example-image:latest` while some were pulled directly from the online repositories using `podman pull`.
2. I saved the images to a tar file using (for example) `podman save docker.io/my-example-image:latest -o my-example-image.tar`
3. I transported the tar files to the air-gapped environment on physical media and loaded them using `podman load -i my-example-image.tar`

When I check the images using `podman images` they all appear in the images list. However, if I try to run a container from one of these images, using `sudo podman run docker.io/my-example-image` I get a long error message:

```
Trying to pull docker.io/my-example-image
Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1}:53: read udp [::1]:50762 ->
  [::1]:53: read: connection refused
Error: unable to pull docker.io/my-example-image: Error initializing source docker://my-example-image:latest:
  error pinging docker registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup
  registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]50762 -> [::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

I get a similar message for images that were acquired from other repositories like `quay.io`

It seems to me that the error is caused by the machine's inability to establish a connection with a registry, which makes sense to me considering that the environment is air-gapped. But I am not sure why podman is even trying to pull these images when they already exist in the environment as confirmed by `podman images`

I have tried using various ways of referencing the image within the `podman run` command including

`sudo podman run docker.io/my-example-image:latest`
`sudo podman run my-example-image`
`sudo podman run my-example-image:latest`

I have tried searching for a solution to this problem to no avail and would very much appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each user has its own container storage.

The user **root** uses the directory */var/lib/containers/*

Normal users use the directory *~/.local/share/containers/*

The command
`podman load -i my-example-image.tar`
will  use the directory *~/.local/share/containers/*

The command
`sudo podman run docker.io/my-example-image`
will use the directory */var/lib/containers*

If you would like to share a read-only container storage between users,
check out the setting *additionalimagestores* in the file *storage.conf*

```
[storage.options]
additionalimagestores = [ "/var/lib/mycontainers",]
```

Reference:
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/image-stores-podman