# Use Podman as alternative to Docker

Tags: podman

I am trying to use Podman as an alternative to Docker Desktop. I have installed Podman on Ubuntu 20.0.4 on Windows 10 and am trying to run an image with Podman on a git repository.

However, after I run the command:

```
sudo podman pull git.companyx.org:5555/test/test-builder/database
```

I get the following error:

```
Error initializing source docker://git.companyx.org:5555/test/test-builder/database:latest reading manifest latest in git.companyx.org:5555/test/test-builder/database errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I am already logged into Podman with command sudo podman login but still I get this error.
unauthorized: authentication required

Comment: As Hiran said, I'd strongly avoid using `sudo`. If you use it once, you'll possibly have to use it for everything else, because images are separated per user, so the root user has its own images Vs. the other users (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307659/why-is-podman-trying-to-pull-an-image-that-already-exists-after-loading-from-fil ). Besides, I think `sudo` is irrelevant here, the authorization issue seems to be with companyx.org, it seems that either the URL is wrong or you're being denied access to their database

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your session within which podman authenticated is not valid for the second sudo. You could verify by running

```
sudo "podman login ...; podman pull git.companyx.org:5555/test/test-builder/database"
```

However one of the big advantages of podman is [you can run it in user space](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-use-podman-on-ubuntu-20-04/). A few [system settings may be required](https://gist.github.com/amshinde/4ec3683fc79b910eb40c60e198a5ab92), but then you can omit sudo completely.